# Let $(C[-1,1],\|.\|_2)$ prove this space isn't a Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $(C[-1,1],\|.\|_2)$ prove this space isn't a Banach space.

**My attempt:** 
Let $\{f_n\}$ such that

$f_n(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             -1 &   if  & x \in [-1,\frac{-1}{n}) 
             \\ nx &  if &  x \in [\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) 
             \\ 1 &  if  & x \in [\frac{1}{n},1]
             \end{array}
   \right.$

Note each $f_n$ is a continuous function in $[-1,1]$ then $\{f_n\}\subset C[-1,1]$ Moreover is easy show that $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C[-1,1]$.

> I'm stuck trying to show that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ but $f\not\in C[-1,1]$.

Comment: You can guess that the limit is $-1$ on $[-1,0)$ and $1$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: What is $f?\,\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Prove that $\|f_n-f\|_2 \to 0$ where $f(x)=-1$ if $x <0$ and $f(x)=1,$ if $x \geq 0$

So the limit is discontinuous at zero,thus it does not belong to the space.

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n \to f$ in your norm, it mist certainly converge pointwise (and the pointwise convergence topology is Hausdorff, so there is at most one pointwise limit). And if the *only* candidate for a limit is not in the more limited subspace the original sequence cannot converge there.